# Calculate conditional probability.

Tags: probability

Assume that $P(A)=\frac{1}{3},P(A\cup C)=\frac{7}{9}, P(B^c|A^c\cap C^c)=\frac{3}{4}$, $P(B|A)=P(B|C)=P(B|A\cap C)=\frac{1}{2}$. Moreover assume that $A$ and $C$ are independent. Calculate $P(A|B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Bayes Rule and some of the given information, we have
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{3}}{P(B)}=\frac{1}{6P(B)}$$
The more involved bit is to calculate $P(B)$.

First we can use $P(A\cup C)$ to calculate $P(C)$ as follows:-
$$P(A\cup C)=P(A)+P(C)-P(A\cap C)=P(A)+P(C)-P(A)P(C)\\\Rightarrow P(C)=\frac{P(A\cup C)-P(A)}{1-P(A)}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Using a Venn diagram for example, you can show that
$$P(B)=P(B\cap A^c\cap C^c)+P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap C)-P(A\cap B\cap C)$$ 
Let us calculate each of the four terms on the right hand side of the above equation.

Now, using the fact that if $A$ and $C$ are independent, their complements will be independent as well, 
$$\begin{align}P(B^c|A^c\cap C^c)&=\frac{P(B^c\cap A^c\cap C^c)}{P(A^c\cap C^c)}=\frac{P(A^c)P(C^c)-P(B\cap A^c\cap C^c)}{P(A^c)P(C^c)}\\\Rightarrow P(B\cap A^c\cap C^c)&=P(A^c)P(C^c)(1-P(B^c|A^c\cap C^c))\\&=\frac{2}{9}\left(1-\frac{3}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{18}\end{align}$$
Also we have
$$\begin{align}P(B\cap A)&=P(B|A)P(A)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}
=\frac{1}{6}\\P(B\cap A)&=P(B|C)P(C)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}
\\P(A\cap B\cap C)&=P(B|A\cap C)P(A\cap C)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{9}\end{align}$$
Putting all the terms together, we have
$$P(B)=\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9}=\frac{4}{9}$$
Having calculated $P(B)$ we are in a position to calculate our desired result:-
$$P(A|B)=\frac{1}{6P(B)}=\frac{3}{8}$$

Comment: I made some mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. I have made my fair share of mistakes too.

Comment: Alijah, your solution is correct and nice, however it seems that using the formula $P(B)=P(B|A\cup C)P(A\cup C)+ P(B|A^c\cap C^c)P(A^c\cap C^c)$ gives the solution in a bit quicker way.

Comment: @Almostsure You are right. My answer was a bit long winded.